# How to concatenate two Tensorflow DataSets?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to load and then augment some image (`160 x 160 x 3`) dataset, where Images are stored in folder, and folder name is label for me. Multiple transformations are being applied to produce copy of data and they need to be `concatenated (or stacked may be)` in order to club data and store them back to disk.

Below is simplest reproducible snippet I am able to write, and I am not able to `append/concatenate/stack` the two dataset.

```
def some_transformation(image, label):
    # do something like rotation, clipping, noise add etc.
    return image, label

userA = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(tf.constant(np.zeros((3, 160, 160, 3))))
userA_label = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(tf.constant(np.zeros((3, 2))))
userA_with_labels = tf.data.Dataset.zip((userA, userA_label))
transformed_userA_w_label = userA_with_labels.map(some_transformation)

userB = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(tf.constant(np.zeros((3, 160, 160, 3))))
userB_label = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(tf.constant(np.zeros((3, 2))))
userB_with_labels = tf.data.Dataset.zip((userB, userB_label))
transformed_userB_w_label = userB_with_labels.map(some_transformation)

print('User A - {}'.format(transformed_userA_w_label))
print('User B - {}'.format(transformed_userB_w_label))
transformed_userA_w_label.concatenate(transformed_userB_w_label)
```

Output of print statements are as follows:

```
User A - <MapDataset shapes: ((3, 160, 160, 3), (3, 2)), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64)>
User B - <MapDataset shapes: ((3, 160, 160, 3), (3, 2)), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64)>
Output ds - <ConcatenateDataset shapes: ((3, 160, 160, 3), (3, 2)), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64)>
```

Expected: `6` image

```
Output ds - <ConcatenateDataset shapes: ((6, 160, 160, 3), (6, 2)), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64)>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key problem here is the use of `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors` vs `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`.

- `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors([t1,t2,t3])` - Creates a dataset where each element of the list is given as a datapoint
- `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(t)` - Create a dataset where one element is one item indexed on the very first axis

From the data you have (i.e. 3 images of size 160x160x3, i.e. `3x160x160x3` ), you need to use the second method. Otherwise all your 3 images are taken in as a single datapoint (which is probably not what you want).

Off to the second problem, the output you show,

```
User A - <MapDataset shapes: ((3, 160, 160, 3), (3, 2)), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64)>
User B - <MapDataset shapes: ((3, 160, 160, 3), (3, 2)), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64)>
Output ds - <ConcatenateDataset shapes: ((3, 160, 160, 3), (3, 2)), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64)>
```

It's just showing what a single element looks like. So you won't see `6` as you would like even if you had the code correct. To see the number of elements you have to iterate the dataset. In your case, you'll see `2` (as this dataset considers all 3 images as a single datapoint).

So to fix up your code, do this,

```
def some_transformation(image, label):
    # do something like rotation, clipping, noise add etc.
    return image, label

userA = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.constant(np.zeros((3, 160, 160, 3))))
userA_label = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(tf.constant(np.zeros((3, 2))))
userA_with_labels = tf.data.Dataset.zip((userA, userA_label))
transformed_userA_w_label = userA_with_labels.map(some_transformation)

userB = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.constant(np.zeros((3, 160, 160, 3))))
userB_label = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(tf.constant(np.zeros((3, 2))))
userB_with_labels = tf.data.Dataset.zip((userB, userB_label))
transformed_userB_w_label = userB_with_labels.map(some_transformation)

print('User A - {}'.format(transformed_userA_w_label))
print('User B - {}'.format(transformed_userB_w_label))
concat_ds = transformed_userA_w_label.concatenate(transformed_userB_w_label)
print(concat_ds)

for i,ii in enumerate(concat_ds):
  print(i)
```

You will see the value of `i` being printed 6 times. Which is what you need.